An integral of several Gaussian densities
Let $f(x \mid \mu, \sigma)$ be the PDF of the Normal/Gaussian distribution.
Is there a way to compute:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{f(x \mid \mu, \sigma_1)}{f(x \mid 0, \sigma_1)+f(x \mid 0, \sigma_2)}dx
$$

It diverges if $\sigma_1\ge\sigma_2$.

Can you say more? Numerical integration gives reasonable results also when $\sigma_1 \ge \sigma_2$.

The integrand is$$\frac{\exp(\mu x-\tfrac12\mu^2)}{1+\frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_2}\exp[-\tfrac12(\sigma_2^{-2}-\sigma_1^{-2})x^2]}.$$Unless the denominator diverges as $x\to\pm\infty$, the $e^{\mu x}$ factor causes divergence as $\mu x\to+\infty$.
